# How do I add an endpoint to a USB gadget and change its addresses?

Tags: linux, usb, usb-device

I am trying to make a USB gadget with bulk in and bulk out for serial communication in the Linux operating system. But I am having difficulty setting device descriptors. I especially want to decide the parameters such as how many endpoints there will be and what their addresses will be, but I could not do it.

under directory
**/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/**
I created **g1** folder using **mkdir g1** command

after this, I saw this,

```
  UDC              bDeviceSubClass  bcdUSB           idProduct        os_desc
  bDeviceClass     bMaxPacketSize0  configs          idVendor         strings
  bDeviceProtocol  bcdDevice        functions        max_speed
```

and I set parameters as this website **https://docs.kernel.org/usb/gadget_configfs.html**

after that, I connected my board to my Ubuntu PC and I saw the following descriptor using **lsusb -d 2020:1111 -v**   command

```
 Bus 003 Device 045: ID 2020:1111 VIA Labs, Inc.          USB2.0 Hub             
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               2.10
      bDeviceClass            0 
      bDeviceSubClass         0 
      bDeviceProtocol         0 
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x2020 
      idProduct          0x1111 
      bcdDevice            0.00
      iManufacturer           1 Manufacturer
      iProduct                2 Product
      iSerial                 3 0
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength       0x0020
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          4 0
        bmAttributes         0xa0
          (Bus Powered)
          Remote Wakeup
        MaxPower              100mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           2
          bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
            bInterval               0
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
            bmAttributes            2
              Transfer Type            Bulk
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
            bInterval               0
    Binary Object Store Descriptor:
      bLength                 5
      bDescriptorType        15
      wTotalLength       0x0016
      bNumDeviceCaps          2
      USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        16
        bDevCapabilityType      2
        bmAttributes   0x0000010e
          BESL Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
        BESL value      256 us 
      SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        16
        bDevCapabilityType      3
        bmAttributes         0x00
        wSpeedsSupported   0x000f
          Device can operate at Low Speed (1Mbps)
          Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
          Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
          Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
        bFunctionalitySupport   1
          Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
        bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
        bU2DevExitLat         511 micro seconds
    can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
    Device Status:     0x0001
      Self Powered
```

everything is ok so far.

The problem is that there are 2 endpoints in this descriptor and I want to increase the number to 4 and write the endpoint addresses I gave myself. What I want to do as an example is this: The endpoints will be EP2(OUT) EP4(OUT) EP6(IN) EP8(IN) instead of EP1(OUT) EP1(IN) 0x81, 0x01 and I want to set the addresses of each as 0x02, 0x04, 0x86, 0x88 respectively, how can I do this?

Thanks,
Best Regards.